# Разобрать проект на node-js и встроить js код в yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

Возникла необходимость встроить [редактор](https://github.com/carstenschaefer/ImagerJs) в проект на yii2.

На странице github есть [инструкция](https://github.com/carstenschaefer/ImagerJs/wiki/Getting-Started:-Standalone) как это сделать, но по гайду не знаю где брать файлы:

- imagerJs.min.css
- imagerJs.min.js
- font-awesome.min.css
- fontawesome-webfont.woff

В исходниках проекта этого нет, и очень странно. Так что, по факту, выходит, что я что-то ни так делаю, либо гайд не рабочий. Так же пробовал взять оригинальные:

- imagerJs.css
- imagerJs.js

И подключить их на страницу, но не выходит.

Редактор запускается локально и работает отлично, но как можно будет лучше провести перенос этого проекта в yii2? С удовольствием выслушаю и попробую ваши советы. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пример

https://carstenschaefer.github.io/ImagerJs/examples/standalone/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[ImagerJs](https://github.com/carstenschaefer/ImagerJs/tree/master/dist)

- [imagerJs.min.css](https://github.com/carstenschaefer/ImagerJs/blob/master/dist/imagerJs.min.css)
- [imagerJs.min.js](https://github.com/carstenschaefer/ImagerJs/blob/master/dist/imagerJs.min.js)

[jquery](https://jquery.com/)

- [jquery-1.10.1.min.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js)
- [jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js)

[fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/)

- [font-awesome.min.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css)

[bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/)

- [bootstrap.min.css](https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css)